# find command search only non hidden directories

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find, command

In the following command i want to search only only the directories which are non hidden how can i do this using the following command .Iwant to ignore hidden directories while searching the log  file

```
      find /home/tom/project/ -name '.log.txt'


   ls /home/tom/project/
   dir1
   dir2
   .backup
   .snapshot/
   .ignore/
```

Comment: you mean directories which are not hidden and have no hidden parents?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
find /home/tom/project -type d -name '.*' -prune -o -name .log.txt -print
```

Comment: not working with `find . -name '.*' -prune -o -print` (will need some regex ...)

Answer (score 2):

This will find all files but ignore those that start with a dot so hidden files.

```
find /home/tom/project/ -type f \( -iname ".log.txt" ! -iname ".*" \)
```

EDIT:
If the above those not work, this should do the trick. It has a better regex.

```
find /home/tom/project/ \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f -name ".log.txt"
```

EDIT2:

The following will exclude hidden folders but will search for the hidden files that have the requested pattern:

```
find /home/tom/project/ \( ! -regex '.*/\..*/..*' \) -type f -name ".log.txt"
```

EDIT3:

The grep solution :) if this doesn't work i'm lost :)

```
find /home/tom/project/ \( ! -regex '.*/\..*/..*' \) -exec grep -l ".log.txt" {} \;
```

EDIT4:

Have you tried the simple solutions?

```
find /home/tom/project/ -type f -name ".log.txt"
```

OR

```
find /home/tom/project/ -type f -name "*" -exec grep -l ".log.txt" {} \;
```

Comment: can you give me an example of folders it still finds?

Comment: find: Filesystem loop detected; `./.snapshot/hourly.0' has the same device number and inode as a directory which is 2 levels higher in the filesystem hierarchy.
find: Filesystem loop detected; `./.snapshot/hourly.1' has the same device number and inode as a directory which is 2 levels higher in the filesystem hierarchy.

Comment: Its still the same.Can u see my edited question.I am also actually searching for .log.txt file .Sorry

Comment: about the log file, does it start with a dot? or can it have like any name followed by .log.txt ?

Comment: I had tried all examples on http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-tell-find-to-not-search-inside-hidden-folders-208169/ :) still not working

Comment: last update :) if this doesn;t work not sure what to suggest next