# How to ignore `.*` folders and files when using `find` command?

Tags: bash, find

I am running `find . -depth -empty` to find empty folders and empty file.

But lots of `.*` folders and files should be ignored,such as `.git`,`.gitignore`,`.nbproject`...
How to write a script to ignore `.*` in `find` command?

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/q/266179/336375

Comment: The Stack Exchange network is rife with cross-site duplicates but the best dupe candidate I could find on Stack Overflow proper is [BASH - ignore hidden files and empty source directory when copying](/questions/19329127/bash-ignore-hidden-files-and-empty-source-directory-when-copying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are several ways to do this, for example:

```
find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f -name "something"
```

The first example won't show you any hidden file or directory.

```
find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*/..*' \) -type f -name "something"
```

The second just discards the hidden directories, showing the hidden files into normal directories.

It's the regular expression option of find.

Here is a complete explanation: [find command search only non hidden directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901738/find-command-search-only-non-hidden-directories)

EDIT 1:

```
find . -type f -not -name ".*"
```